# Form validation display same error message for all fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The Html: Below is a simple form have 2 fields firstname and lastname.

## Form Validation

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Firstname : <input type="text" placeholder="first name" class="fname" name="fname" />
    <span class="err1"></span><br>
    Lastname : <input type="text" placeholder="last name" class="lname" name="lname" />
    <span class="err2"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The Jquery:

```
(function(){
            $('.submit_form').click(function() {                
                    var fail = validate_firstname()
                        fail += validate_lastname();

                    if(fail == "") {
                        return true;
                    } else {                        
                        return false;
                    }               
            });

            function validate_firstname(){
                var fname = $('.fname').val();
                if(fname.length == 0) {
                    $('.err1').text("required");
                } else if(fname.length < 5) {
                    $('.err1').text("Minimum 5 letter");
                }
            }

            function validate_lastname(){
                var lname = $('.fname').val();
                if(lname.length == 0) {
                    $('.err2').text("required");
                } else if(lname.length < 5) {
                    $('.err2').text("Minimum 5 letter");
                }
            }
        })(jQuery);
```

Now when I **submit** the form without any thing in input fields. It displays **Required** for **both fields**. But if I leave **first name** blank and  enter some text in **last name** say 'aaa' and then submit. It again gives the same error  **Required** for both fields. 
But it should show **required** for first name and **minimum 5 letter** for last name. How can i display the correct errors for each field. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lastname validation replace below line write wrong class name

```
var lname = $('.lname').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a Typing Mistake
please Check This Line and Change again.

```
var lname = $('.lname').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo error - you have used `$('.fname').val()` in both cases.

```js
(function() {
  $('.submit_form').click(function() {
    var fail = validate_firstname()
    fail += validate_lastname();

    if (fail == "") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  function validate_firstname() {
    var fname = $('.fname').val();
    if (fname.length == 0) {
      $('.err1').text("required");
    } else if (fname.length < 5) {
      $('.err1').text("Minimum 5 letter");
    }
  }

  function validate_lastname() {
    var lname = $('.lname').val();
    if (lname.length == 0) {
      $('.err2').text("required");
    } else if (lname.length < 5) {
      $('.err2').text("Minimum 5 letter");
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  Firstname :
  <input type="text" placeholder="first name" class="fname" name="fname" />
  <span class="err1"></span>
  <br>Lastname :
  <input type="text" placeholder="last name" class="lname" name="lname" />
  <span class="err2"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form>
```